# Replacing a double for loop to increase speed

Tags: r, performance, optimization

I'm estimating conditional marginal densities and evaluating them at new observations. I am then inputting the estimates into an array. This code is slow, and I haven't been able to speed it up significantly. Any help is much appreciated. Here's a small reproducible example:

```
library(sm)

y <- rep(1:6, 30)
K <- length(unique(y))
X <- matrix(rnorm(180 * 1000), nrow=180)
newx <- matrix(rnorm(20 * 1000), nrow=20)

f.estimates <- array(dim=c(dim(newx)[1], dim(X)[2], K - 1))
g.estimates <- array(dim=c(dim(newx)[1], dim(X)[2], K - 1))
for(k in 1:(K - 1)) {
  for(j in 1:dim(X)[2]) {
    f.estimates[, j, k] <- sm.density(X[y <= k, j], 
                              eval.points=newx[, j], 
                              display="none")$estimate
    g.estimates[, j, k] <- sm.density(X[y > k, j], 
                              eval.points=newx[, j],
                              display="none")$estimate
  }
}
```

Comment: You could replace your inner loop with two `sapply` functions. This may have a slight performance increase on the order of 0.2. Take a look, you may have to transpose the resulting matrices.

Comment: Your problem can also be done in parallel.  Here is good reference to start with.  Look into `foreach`.  Here is a good resource  http://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-go-parallel-in-r-basics-tips/.

Answer (score 1):

Setup:

```
library(sm)

y <- rep(1:6, 30)
K <- length(unique(y))
X <- matrix(rnorm(180 * 1000), nrow=180)
newx <- matrix(rnorm(20 * 1000), nrow=20)

f.estimates <- array(dim=c(dim(newx)[1], dim(X)[2], K - 1))
g.estimates <- array(dim=c(dim(newx)[1], dim(X)[2], K - 1))
```

Using `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)
cond <- expand.grid(k=1:(K-1), j=1:dim(X)[2]) #conditions, to avoid multiple **ply loops

f.estimates <- aaply(cond, 1, function(c) sm.density(X[y <= c[,1], c[,2]], 
                                                 eval.points=newx[, c[,2]], 
                                                 display="none")$estimate)
f.estimates <- aperm(f.estimates, c(3,2,1))

g.estimates <- aaply(cond, 1, function(c) sm.density(X[y > c[,1], c[,2]], 
                                                 eval.points=newx[, c[,2]], 
                                                 display="none")$estimate)
g.estimates <- aperm(g.estimates, c(3,2,1))
```

Using `aperm()` transposes the order of the dimensions of the array, like `t()` does for matrices.